# Insert parent-child rows using Parallel programming

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have a method that iterates the rows using for loop and inside that for loop call the DNN API that inserts a parent child row into the database. The maximum to insert the data is 1000 rows per execution. I tested it on my local machine the performance is very slow. I am thinking to use a Parallel Programming, but not sure on how to implement this since there is a dependency on data insertion because of parent child relationship. And I am not sure if this is a good approach to use Parallel programming. Any help please?

Sample code

```
        private void AddTab()
        {
           for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { 
               TabController tabController = new TabController();
               var portalSettings = new 
                  DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalSettings(info.PortalId);

                TabInfo tab = new TabInfo();
                tab.PortalID = info.PortalId;
                tab.TabName = info.TabName;
                tab.Title = info.Title;
                tab.Description = info.TabName;
                tab.KeyWords = info.TabName;
                tab.IsVisible = info.IsVisible;
                tab.DisableLink = info.IsDisabled;
                tab.ParentId = info.ParentId == null ? Null.NullInteger : info.ParentId.GetValueOrDefault();
                tab.IsDeleted = false;
                tab.Url = "";
                tab.SkinSrc = "[G]Skins/HRT.Portal.DNNThemes.Default/Home.ascx";
                tab.ContainerSrc = portalSettings.DefaultPortalContainer;
                tab.IsSuperTab = false;


                 var parentPage = tabController.GetTab(portalSettings.HomeTabId, info.PortalId);


            //clone parent page permissions
                 foreach (TabPermissionInfo permission in parentPage.TabPermissions.ToList())
                 {
                     tab.TabPermissions.Add(permission);
                 }


                int tabId = tabController.AddTab(tab, true);
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of your current implementation, please?

Comment: You need to identify the bottleneck. Could be that your database isn't indexed the right way, or could be the network, who knows? It is not likely to be CPU-bound, so multithreading is probably not going to help (although `async` may).

Comment: @Turner Bass, I had updated the question with code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: John Wu, the adding of rows has a lot of logic behind it, since it is a DNN API, so I have no control about it. So if I use asynchronous, I think it will not help to improve the performance since it will execute the whole logic. That is why I am thinking of Parallel programming since I can partition the data and execute the partition on different threads.